How to create an encrypted RAM-disk as a regular user?
Is it possible to create an encrypted RAM-disk as a regular user (without requiring sudo). (with FUSE or similar tools)?

Note that the use-case here is to edit sensitive data, there are of course in-memory considerations too - where users may also want to encrypt their swap.

Where would you store the encryption key? On the face of it your request may seem reasonable, but if you can't trust the local system to enforce access control for RAM, you can't trust it to keep the key secure either.

It could for example be kept on a USB-security token, passed as an environment variable.

Environment variables are kept in RAM. If any attacker could access RAM to read your RAM FS, he can access RAM to read your environment variable.

A system that handles sensitive data should not even grant access to users without access to the data. If you need to edit unencrypted sensitive data, you should do so on a system specifically set up for that.  If you don't trust the admins of that system, then you can't use it.

On (at least) Ubuntu systems, you can use the directory tree at /run/user/[yourUserID], eg. /run/user/1000.  You can see your userID with the command id --user.
/run uses tmpfs, which uses volatile memory presented as a file system.  That directory is owned by you and readable/writable only by you.
NEW Since Linux 6.4, there has been an option noswap that disables swap for the tmpfs filesystem, otherwise swapping of tmpfs data is enabled by default.  Note that this setting can't be changed after the filesystem is mounted, ie. trying to use -o noswap,remount will fail on any tmpfs filesystem that was mounted normally.  See the tmpfs(5) manpage on a system with a 6.4 or later kernel.
If your kernel doesn't support noswap, or if noswap wasn't specified at mount time, ensure that the swap partition is encrypted (thanks @ideasman42), this will protect your data at rest.
Note that if you're using vim to edit your data -- even vim -n to avoid creating a vim swap file -- you may still be writing some data to persistent storage.  The file ~/.vimrc (or a system configuration file) may specify mandatory storage of an arbitrary amount of undo data.  In my case vim wouldn't be suitable, because I have the following in my .vimrc.
set undofile                " Save undos after file closes
set undodir=$HOME/.vim/undo " where to save undo histories
set undolevels=10000        " How many undos

Similarly, you should check that your editing/manipulation doesn't create files elsewhere.

Re: If all you need is a way to manipulate data without it being stored persistently or transmitted, this is only the case if your swap partition is encrypted.

@ideasman42 Thanks, I thought that the default was not to swap tmpfs if needed.  I'll update my answer and keep digging.


Note that the use-case here is to edit sensitive data, there are of course in-memory considerations too

If you can't trust the host, you can't trust the host.
While this may be feasible when you're in control of hardware (e.g. keep keys in CPU registers), it becomes impossible once you're doing things in usermode: the key material has to be in RAM, and storing secrets in RAM is what you want to avoid.
Environment variables - as you suggest in a comment - is a memory location. An attacker that can read your ramdisk can read your environment variable.
This problem is solvable with trusted computing and a secure boot chain, but that's outside what you ask.
